# Creating Columns with pyodbc - Not Working

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

I have a class which uses the pyodbc library successfully - it can perform a variety of reads from the database (so the connection and DSN are hunky dory).

What I've being trying to implement are functions to write and delete columns from tables in a sql database (the same one I'm able to read from).

I have tested the calls using isql commands and I can see the changes occur in my database. For example;

```
SQL> ALTER TABLE DunbarGen ADD testCol float(4)
SQLRowCount returns -1
```

Adds a new column to the table from the terminal (this works). I have a code which, I think, should replicate this command - which causes no errors in my class - and looks like this;

```
    def createColumn(self, columnName, tableName, isFloat, isDateTime, isString):
    if isFloat:
        typeOf = 'float(4)'
    elif isDateTime:
        typeOf = 'datetime2'
    elif isString:
        typeOf = 'text'
    else:
        return False
    self.cursor.execute("ALTER TABLE " + tableName + " ADD " + columnName + " " + typeOf)
    print 'command has executed'
```

Do I need to do something else with the pyodbc class to finalize the command or something?

Thanks!

Comment: as a standalone statement?

Comment: That worked, but as self.cursor.commit() in my context, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.cursor.commit()
```

After the execute function has been called.